# Using Php Filter with Ckeditor?

Tags: wysiwyg, input-formats

I need to use Php Filter with ckeditor. 
Problem is that Ckeditor change this:

> `<?php echo "hello";?>`

to

> `<p>&lt;?php echo "hello";?&gt;</p>`

How can I solve this?

I already added this:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

under **Custom JavaScript configuration** at: admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full

But it didn't help.

I also make sure I checked **Php evaluator** under **Enabled filters** at admin/config/content/formats/full_html

Comment: I strongly suggest you to reconsider. PHP filter is really asking for trouble. In pure CKEditor you would use sth like `CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource.push( /<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g );` I don't approve doing it, but should work. Don't know how to wrap it in Drupal.

Comment: I know, but I need to insert a custom view block and this module is not working for me: https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view I already posted my issue (https://www.drupal.org/node/2488534) but I get no help so far. Then the only way I see is using php.

Answer (score 2):

Change the 'insertElement' function for 'insertHtml' function

```
editor.addCommand('phpcode', {
  exec : function() {
    editor.insertHtml('<div id="phpcode"><?php echo "hello"; ?></div>');
  }
});
```

Hope it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

In /admin/config/content/formats/full_html try unchecking the Correct faulty and chopped off HTML box. Maybe it thinks your php is html.